# undefined method `each' for "1":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, runtime-error

Im getting a weird string error when trying to assign attributes on a Rails model:

```
# POST /apartments
  # POST /apartments.xml
  def create
    @apartment = Apartment.new(params[:apartment])
```

Params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Kxxxxx=",
 "apartment"=>{"street"=>"123 Main St",
 "unit"=>"",
 "hide_address"=>"0",
 "city"=>"White Plains",
 "state"=>"New York",
 "zipcode"=>"10840",
 "country"=>"United States",
 "price"=>"4000",
 "security_deposit"=>"",
 "application_fee"=>"",
 "bedrooms"=>"4",
 "bathrooms"=>"3",
 "size"=>"",
 "available_date"=>"",
 "unit_amenities"=>["air conditioning"],
 "description"=>"",
 "rooms"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Publish Your Listing"}
```

Error

```
NoMethodError in ApartmentsController#create
undefined method `each' for "1":String
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does your Apartment object try to iterate through params[:apartment]["rooms"] ?

Comment: I can't even find the word `each` anywhere in my model or controller...

Comment: Well, how does your Apartment model define its "rooms" attribute?

Comment: Yup, before it was just an integer column, but it looks like I created an association with the same name. Now I removed it, and it works. Ooops...